# Is derived type also becomes owner for dependency property defined in base class (in WPF/XAML)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

In one of the module, I have seen following style being set.

```
<Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation To="300" Duration="0:0:1.5" 
                    AccelerationRatio="0.10" DecelerationRatio="0.25" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Note that `TargetType` is `Rectangle` while, `Storyboard.TargetProperty` is `Canvas.Width`.
The style/trigger still is working correctly. It is animating the `Rectangle.width` property.

I understand that In Storyboard.TargetProperty (or anywhere else in XAML), we have to use [PropertyPath syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.aspx), which is like `(ownerType.PropertyName)`.

My question is how setting animation on `Canvas.Width` is animating `Rectangle.Width`

1. Is it because Canvas.Width, Rectangle.Width or FrameworkElement.Width all points to FrameowrkElement.Width property, because Width is defined in FrameworkElement, and Canvas/Rectangle are derived from it.
2. Or Is it because, by virtue of Inheritance, Canvas and Rectangle both also becomes owner of the dependency property.

Comment: Interesting !!!!. Curious to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the XAML compiler resolves `Canvas.Width` by looking for a static field called `WidthProperty` on `Canvas`. Since `Canvas` inherits from `FrameworkElement`, a reference to `Canvas.WidthProperty` resolves to `FrameworkElement.WidthProperty`.

Because `Rectangle` also inherits from `FrameworkElement`, animating `Canvas.WidthProperty` is the same as animating `Rectangle.WidthProperty`, is the same as animating `FrameworkElement.WidthProperty`.

Comment: Not sure if it really is that simple. First, it wouldn't be a static property named `WidthProperty`, but a static readonly field instead. Second, i can successfully animate a property (by a Storyboard defined in XAML as described in the question) whose DependencyProperty field does not adhere to the `<name>Property` naming convention.

Comment: @Clemens: thanks, corrected the typo. I believe the XAML compiler falls back to attempting to resolve a property if the static field cannot be found. If you managed to animate a property without a backing field and via a type that is not in the type hierarchy of the object being animated, then I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Width Property` is a `Property` of the `FrameworkElement` Class you can enter every `Control` which inherits from `FrameworkElement`

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)"
```

But my favorite is:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGrid.Width)"
```

Try it. It will work!

Comment: It is working. I want to understand why? Due to inheritance or due to Dependency Property Ownership. Not finding any credible MSDN reference about this issue

Comment: It is really easy. The `Width` Property exists on EVERY Class which is inherited by `FrameworkElement`. You are not binding to the actual `Width` Property of your Rectangle. The Framework searches for the right Property. Please don't forget to mark the Question as answered :)

Comment: I want to understand how dependency property work in inheritance.
[FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Inherits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.inherits.aspx), [DependencyProperty.AddOwner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597484.aspx) Method etc. Note that Dependency Property are declared as static readonly, with CLR instance property as wrapper.

Comment: In WPF it's all about `Dependency Properties`. `FrameworkElement` has a Property called `WidthProperty`. This Property can be animated. When you are refering to the Width Property in a storyboard it doesn't matter if you are using `Canvas`, `DataGrid`, `Framwork`... It is all refering to the same `DependencyProperty`.